# Proving the Commutative, Associative and Distributive laws of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have looked all over the web and can't find any elegant proofs for the commutative, associative and distributive laws of Sets:

Commutative Law
$$A\cup B = B\cup A, \ A\cap B = B\cap A$$
Associative Law
$$A\cup (B\cup C) = (A\cup B)\cup C, \ A\cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap C$$
Distributive Law
$$A\cap (B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C), A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C) $$

How would these be proved in an elegant way?

The question comes from Tom M Apostol Calculus Volume I book. He gives an example proof of the commutative law as follows.

> Let $X=A\cup B$, $Y=B\cup A$. To prove that $X=Y$ we prove that $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$. Suppose that $x\in X$. Then $x$ is in at least one of $A$ or $B$. Hence, $x$ is in at least one of $B$ or $A$; so $x\in Y$. Thus, every element of $X$ is also in $Y$, so $X\subseteq Y$. Similary, we find that $Y\subseteq X$, so $X=Y$

He doesn't presuppose knowledge of truth tables. Can this proof be written in a more mathematical and concise way? How would I go about writing concise proofs for the other laws?

I understand the logic, but I am new to mathematical language.

Comment: Define "elegant". These proofs are pretty straightforward and almost trivial.

Comment: Sorry, by elegant I mean without using too many English words.

Answer (score 6):

You can use truth tables. Let $0$ indicate $x\not\in X$ and $1$ indicate $x\in X$, where $X$ is a set.

For example, the first distributive law:

$$\begin{array} {ccc|c|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&(B\cup C)&A\cap (B\cup C)&(A\cap B)&(A\cap C)&(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1
\end{array}
$$

Column $5$ equals column $8$.

---

In response to the updated question, look at the definitions of union and intersection:

$$A\cup B = \{x|x\in A \lor x\in B\}$$
$$A\cap B = \{x|x\in A \land x\in B\}$$

Both $\lor$ and $\land$ are commutative for example (but you need a truth table to prove it), and so, by extending this concept over the definitions of $\cup$ and $\cap$, are these operators, i.e.:

$$A\cup B = \{x|x\in A \lor x\in B\} = \{x|x\in B \lor x\in A\} = B\cup A$$

Comment: Thanks. This method makes sense, but is very long. Is there a more concise way to write this mathematically?

Comment: hmm, not really, you get to axiomatic foundations quite quickly. anyway, this proof doesn't use many English words.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm updating my question, which may clarify the meaning of my question better.

Comment: @JamieFearon I think this is an excellent answer (though I wouldn't agree that you need a truth table to prove it). When you say "more mathematical" you might be meaning "more symbolic". Try splitting each sentence of the Tom Apostol proof onto its own line and rewriting it using symbolic maths. You'll likely get something similar to the train of thought in JMPs last line.
If that doesn't answer your question, you probably need to clarify more, otherwise I suggest accepting the answer.